# Puppet configuration is getting applied everywhere

Tags: puppet

I am new in Puppet and just facing very unusual problem in that, my Puppet master is running and all agents are configured to that master perfectly.

Files in Puppet Master:

Now here is my **site.pp** file :

```
class fileForNodeA{

     file { "/tmp/hello.txt" : 
         content => "This is hello.txt"
     }
}

class fileForNodeB{
     file{ "/tmp/hello.txt" : 
         content => "This is hello1.txt"
     }
}

node  'NodeA'{
   include fileForNodeA
}

node  'NodeB'{
   include fileForNodeB
}
```

Now the hostnames of clients are NodeA and NodeB respectively :

On NodeA or NodeB when I say :

```
puppet agent --no-daemonize --verbose --waitforcert 60 --test
```

It shows this

```
Could not retrieve catalog from remote server : Error 400 on server : Could not find|
default node or by name with 'NodeA.com' .....
Notice : Using cached catalog
Info : Applying configuratiuon version '1234567890' 
Notice : Finished catalog run in 0.06 seconds
```

After this statement when I browse the dir **/tmp** it says two files namely **hello.txt**
and **hello1.txt**, I am bit confused when it is saying "Could not find..blah blah", then why it applies both the part of NodeA and NodeB?

Please shed some light on to it, if I am doing something wrong how to configure the things according to the nodes setup ?

Please help>>>Thanks AV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add this as first line in your site.pp

node default {
}

Enjoy.

Comment: Care to elaborate? :)

Comment: Puppet client when while connecting to master look for default configuration and in absence of it applies complete config.

Once you specify default config puppet client does not break and finds its configuration and apply.

Puppet devs should do something about it.